# How to get cookie renewal information in .NET Core 3.1 with CookieAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .NET Core 3.1 and would like to know how to get cookie renewal information when a user's login cookie expire time is extended.

I have tried adding the following code to `startup.cs`, but `context.ShouldRenew` always returns `false`, even though the login cookie's expire time has been extended:

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Member/Login");
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                        {
                            if (context.ShouldRenew)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Cookie expire time should be update");
                                // I want to write some text
                                // But `context.ShouldRenew` always get false
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

What should be the correct way to get cookie renewal information in .NET Core 3.1 with CookieAuthentication?

Comment: Could you please tell me which information you want to get from cookie renewal? Normally, if you set the SlidingExpiration, it will auto renew the cookie when the request come to the server.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have a custom cache that records the current user's login account and limits the number of logins. I hope that when the cookie expiration time is extended, I can handle and extend the cache time here in same time

Comment: I suggest you could write a middleware to check the cookie expire time and extend the cache time as I said before the expire time will be extend automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use another property to detect if cookie has expired. Description of the property [`ShouldRenew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookievalidateprincipalcontext.shouldrenew?view=aspnetcore-3.1#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-cookies-cookievalidateprincipalcontext-shouldrenew):

> If true, the cookie **will be renewed**

In other words: It can be false, even if cookies have expired.

You can use `HttpContext` property to check if any cookies have expired:

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
    {
        var cookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["YOUR_COOKIE_NAME"];

        if (cookie.Expires < DateTime.Now)
        {
            // Your code here...
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```